# All buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script in Jitpack

Tags: java, android, gradle, jitpack, build-script

I am trying to publish my android library with jitpack. But getting `buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks error.`
I have already referred to this question : [Getting 'buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks' error in jitpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193461/getting-buildscript-blocks-must-appear-before-any-plugins-blocks-error-i) but did not found any solution.

**Error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/home/jitpack/build/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/home/jitpack/build/build.gradle': 26: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script
  
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block
  
   @ line 26, column 1.
     buildscript {
     ^
  
  1 error
```

*This is what my project level gradle looks like:*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.4"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*This is what my app level gradle looks like:*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id "com.jfrog.bintray"
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.siddydevelops.logutil"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

*My gradle version is 7.0.2.*

I am pretty sure that this block is causing the error: (in project level gradle)

```
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.4"
}
```

I cant move it to app level gradle.

Answer (score 9):

i have the same problem too, i just change the position inside build.gradle project like this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```